# Change identifier from Color to Colour C#/VS2013

Tags: c#, colors

I'm English and the constant use of Color in Visual Studio is starting to wear away my brain. Can I change it to accept Colour?

(Changed title from 'Keyword' to 'Identifier' to BoltClock's point (for ease of future search))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure:

```
using Colour = System.Windows.Media.Color;
```

This is known as a [`using` alias directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx).

For the record, both of these are not keywords, but identifiers. Keywords are tied to the language rather than the framework, and so are treated (and in most cases highlighted) differently from identifiers.

Comment: Thanks, and appreciate the clarification on nomenclature :)